# Android M Permission for AppWidgetProvider

Tags: java, android, android-activity, permissions, widget

I have android widget.The application not have any activity.The first time widget add to home screen on Android M ,I want get Permission for write on external storage but this need to activity.there is way when add android widget to home screen get permission(in class appWidgetProvider)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The application not have any activity

You will need to add one, or keep your `targetSdkVersion` below 23.

> there is way when add android widget to home screen get permission(in class appWidgetProvider)?

No. You can only request permissions from an activity.

Comment: Can i start activity when widget add for first time and get permission then close activity and update appWidgetPrivider ?

Comment: @Mortezaj8: In theory, an [app widget configuration activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring) can request a permission, though I have never tried it. If that fails, you can show something in the app widget itself (or raise a `Notification`) indicating that you need a permission, and the activity that you start from there (e.g., tap on the app widget) can request the permission.

Comment: I think i was set custom layout for first time to widget to click and start activity for permission.you right there is no way(i think).